# lim sup inequality for sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n$ and $\limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n$ exist, we know it is true  that:

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_n +b_n) \leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n + \limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n $$

But is that  true for this example?

Suppose that $a_n =1-n$ and $b_n=n$ ,then we have $\limsup_{n\to\infty}(a_n +b_n)=1$, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n=-\infty$ and $\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n =\infty $.

If the inequality  is true we must have $1\leq\infty  -\infty $.that is not well defined.what do we say in this case?we say the inequality is false in such examples?

Answer (score 1):

In your example $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n$ and $\limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n$ do **not** exist (that is where the problem is).

Comment: yes that is right.but in all cases when limits don't exist this inequality is true. The problem just come in examples the same as I said  when one limit is $+\infty $ and the other  is $-\infty $

Comment: "when limits don't exist this inequality is true".. If the limits don't exit, then the inequality makes no sens (you can't even write it since you have to deal with object that don't exist). It's like to say: "For every $x \in\emptyset$ we have $x=3$"

Comment: @user115608 Should I clarify something in more details?

Comment: @Surb I disagree with your answer. The limsup of **any** sequence exists, and is allowed to take the values $\pm \infty$. The caveat is that the stated inequality is not universally true. It is true as long as the right-hand side is not of the form "$\infty - \infty$".

Comment: @UmbertoP. "The limsup of any sequence exists, and is allowed to take the values $\pm\infty$." Well this is not how I learned it in my lectures (where $\limsup/\liminf$ is defined for bounded sequences only). And, to me, this sounds a bit like: "This statement is true except for all the cases where it is wrong"

Comment: The proper definition of the limsup of a sequence is $$\limsup a_n = \inf_{k \ge 1} \sup_{n \ge k} a_n.$$ This is a well-defined extended real number for any sequence $\{a_k\}$. The inequality in the OP should be stated as : if $\{a_k\}$ and $\{b_k\}$ are **bounded** sequences then $\limsup (a_k + b_k) \le \limsup a_k + \limsup b_k$. It turns out to be true for certain other unbounded sequences, but not all.

Comment: @UmbertoP. if you say so... For me the existence of $\limsup$ was implicitly meaning that the sequence is bounded. If you want to add your comments as an answer I'd be happy to upvote it and delete mine.